# Disabling autocommenting for all filetypes

Tags: vim, ftplugin

I turned on `filetype plugin` for some rails vim plugins I added, but a side effect of this seems to be that now autocommenting has been enabled in all filetypes (for instance, if I start a line with `#`, the next line, either by <kbd>Enter</kbd> in insert mode or <kbd>O</kbd>, etc. to enter insert mode, will also get a `#`).

I found a [guide](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_auto-comment_when_editing_C/C%2B%2B_files) to disabling the auto-commenting `formatoptions`, and added the following to my .vimrc:

```
au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=cro
```

However, I am still running into problems -- unless I explicitly `:source .vimrc`, (or enter the `setlocal ...` directly), it is not taking effect. I determined that this is the case because vim's ftplugins are overriding my options with their own.

I then found a [second guide](http://peox.net/articles/vimconfig.html) which talks about using an after ftplugin script to make changes after the ftplugin scripts have run, however their solution is to create symlinks for every single filetype in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin to a central file, and this seems to be kludgy to me.

Is there any way to create a generic after-ftplugin script or am I approaching this problem incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about an "after" plugin?  Create a file in `~/.vim/after/plugin/` called `noAutoComments.vim` (or whatever) and place your autocmd in that?

Edit:

The reason this works?  I'm only guessing here, but I have a feeling that the `autocmd` in the `~/.vimrc` file is getting removed by some other file (but before the "after" files are getting sourced).

I ended up removing my `~/.vim` directory and replaced my `~/.vimrc` with the following 3 lines:

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=cro
```

With only these lines in my `~/.vimrc` and no `~/.vim/` directory, the `autocmd` seems to work as expected (Vim 7.1).

For any file that I edit:

```
:verbose set formatoptions?
formatoptions=ql
      Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

I have yet to determine what file (plugin) is causing this issue however.

Comment: Even though I can see from `:scriptnames` that the ftplugins are still being loading after my after plugin, this seems to do the trick! Any reason you could think of why this would work?

Comment: @Daniel: My only guess is that some other file is removing all of the `autocmd` s when it's loaded and that occurs before the sourcing of the "after" files.  I'll update my answer with my findings.

Comment: thanks for all your help, I seem to have figured out what is going on and have added an answer to explain it.

Comment: It doesn't work when the .vimrc file itself were edited. Strange.

Answer (score 5):

I've done some more investigation and it seems that the location of my `autocmd` within my .vimrc file determines if `formatoptions` will be overridden by vim's ftplugins or not. Using `vim --noplugin` to disable all external plugins, I found the following results:

If my vimrc looks like:

```
au FileType * setl fo-=cro
filetype plugin indent on
```

The result of `:verbose set fo?` is:

```
formatoptions=croql
  Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/ruby.vim
```

However, if the lines in my vimrc are reversed:

```
filetype plugin indent on
au FileType * setl fo-=cro
```

The result of `:verbose set fo?` is:

```
formatoptions=ql
  Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

... which is the desired result. So it seems that the `autocmd` needs to be specified after filetype plugins are enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason this might not be taking effect...

From `:he :set-=`:

```
            When the option is a list of flags, {value} must be
            exactly as they appear in the option.  Remove flags
            one by one to avoid problems.
```

I have

```
    " Turn off auto-commenting
    au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=c
    au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=r
    au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=o
```

because I've run into this.

Comment: My ~/.vimrc includes:  

  `au FileType,BufNewFile,BufRead * se fo-=r fo-=o fo-=c fo-=q`

Answer (score 1):

Using one of the various `autocmd` events to set the configuration option should work if you find the right one, but I'd start by running:

```
:verbose set formatoptions?
```

This will tell you where the option was set, which may make it easier to determine which autocmd to use.  Alternatively, if you don't mind a bit of minor hacking, the way I'd probably do it is just to find out where it's set in the plugin and comment out that line (and make a note of it in case you ever upgrade the plugin).  You could also contact the plugin's author and ask them to make it a configurable option.

For the available `autocmd` events, read this:

```
:help {event}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Al. I actually had checked through verbose before, and it returned `Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/ruby.vim`... so it's vim's own ftplugins that are setting the value last. I'm not sure how to use this information to determine which event to use though.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried solutions proposed by many, but none of them worked for me, but I found one very simple workaround, namely, in your ~/.bash_aliases:

```
    # vim without auto comment
    alias vi="vi +'set fo-=cro'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue and I finally works with the following  lines:

```
syntax on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=cro
```

I think the key here is that the  `autocmd` is place after the `filetype plugin on`.